# Can't make razor_imu_9dof

Tags: ros, imu, razor-imu-9dof

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to compile razor_imu_9dof under diamond (?), but I get this error:
CMake Error" the source directory "/home/paralax2/github/razor_imu_9dof/razor_imu does not exist.

I don't care about paralax2, can I use this package?  Found a razor.launch file.

So I get 37 packages with 1 failure.  Is it the git depository?

Thanks,

Alan KM6VV

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57482/can%27t-make-razor_imu_9dof/) by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2013-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The path was wrong for the source directory.

I edited cmake_install.cmake, makefile and cmakecache.txt files to fix the path, and ran rosmake.  this time all compiles!

Talking with the author (who suggested path fix), probably didn't need to do rosmake, as the files are Python (I saw some Lisp as well).

Alan KM6VV

---

Originally posted by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) with karma: 191 on 2013-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0